# Why different shapes in RNNCell created from scratch in numpy to pytorch?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to recreate [pytorch's RNNCell](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.nn.RNNCell.html) in numpy using the same equation available in the documentation of RNNCell.

```
import numpy as np

inputs = 10
hiddens = 6
rows = 3

#input data
x = np.random.rand(rows,inputs)

w_ih = np.random.rand(hiddens,inputs)
w_hh = np.random.rand(hiddens,hiddens)
b_ih = np.random.rand(hiddens,1)
b_hh = np.random.rand(hiddens,1)

# initial hidden values
h = np.zeros((hiddens,1))

h = w_ih @ x.T + b_ih + w_hh @ h + b_hh
print("Shape",h.shape)
```

In this approach the output shape is `(6,3)`. In order to verify this I created a sample code in pythorch RNNCell itself

```
import torch
torch_rnn = torch.nn.RNNCell(inputs,hiddens)
xx = torch.rand(rows,inputs)
print("shape",torch_rnn(xx).shape)
```

Here the shape is `(3,6)` transpose of my numpy implementation.

Why the numpy implementation is giving wrong shape for hidden state?

For initial hidden values I chose this way to `h = np.zeros((hiddens,1))` initialize it which is wrong. How should I initialize hidden values for my RNNCell?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how accurate is this answer but rearranging the matrix multiplication order currently gives the expected result and the hidden state is initialized as `(rows,hiddens)`

```
import numpy as np

inputs = 10
hiddens = 4
rows = 3

#input data
x = np.random.rand(rows,inputs)

w_ih = np.random.rand(hiddens,inputs)
w_hh = np.random.rand(hiddens,hiddens)
b_ih = np.random.rand(1,hiddens)
b_hh = np.random.rand(1,hiddens)

# initial hidden values
h = np.zeros((rows,hiddens))

h = x @ w_ih.T + b_ih + h @ w_hh + b_hh
print("Shape",h.shape)
```